# Determine the number of times,the output displays after compiling and executing

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure this out:

```
int i = 11;
while(i>=0);
{ 
System.out.println("Computer");
i--;
}
```

Now my question is How many times the code will display the string "Computer"?
I tried to compile but failed and this error pop out

**Could not find or load main class undefined**

Comment: You need to put this code in a class, in a main method. You could find this in the most basic of Java tutorials.

Comment: first compile your code. try to use some IDE like eclipse. it will make your life much easier.

Comment: Let use the new documentation provided by SO : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/java-overview/378/creating-a-new-java-program#t=201610141020050719936 you will see a nice Hello World to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This:

```
  public class test{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                   int i = 11;
                  while(i>=0);
                   { 
                         System.out.println("Computer");
                     i--;
                 }
         }
    }
```